# Can I rely on nil UIView returning CGRectZero for its frame?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Yes, I saw this:

> If the method returns a struct, as defined by the Mac OS X ABI Function Call Guide to be returned in registers, then a message sent to nil returns 0.0 for every field in the struct. Other struct data types will not be filled with zeros.

I just don't get it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using recent versions of the LLVM Compiler (Xcode 4.2 or later), then yes, messaging `nil` with a struct-returning method will produce a zero-filled struct. In the case of `CGRect`, that means a rect equal to `CGRectZero`.

Source: [Greg Parker](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html), who works at Apple on the ObjC runtime.

Comment: See the doc I quoted in the question. It is from the official The Objective-C Programming Language. You can see it already states that struct returned will be zero-filled, but only for those "as defined by the Mac OS X ABI Function Call Guide to be returned in registers". I'm not sure what the tweet above means. Does it mean any struct will now be zero-filled, including those "Other struct data types that will not be filled with zeros in the old days"?

Comment: Yes; it used to be that in most cases, messaging nil would not return a zero-filled struct, except in the lucky case where the ABI that the struct return value was to be passed in registers. (Only for very small structs.) Stack-based return values were not zero-filled. But with the LLVM compiler in Xcode 4.2 or greater, they are now *always* zero filled.

Comment: In addition to the tweet above, it was also mentioned in one of the sessions at WWDC 2011.

Comment: Is there some place that describes how this works underneath? Does the compiler zero the memory before calling `objc_msgSend_stret`?

Comment: Based on a post on @gparker's blog (http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html), "Struct return is undefined if you call objc_msgSend_stret() directly." So yes, it sounds like the compiler zeroes before calling.