# What happens if you pass nil at runtime to a parameter that shouldn't accept that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, location, cllocationmanager

Say I have a method that takes a CLLocationCoordinate2D. I can't pass nil directly to that in code; the compiler complains. However, the following compiles. So what happens at runtime?

```
CLLocation* loc = nil;
[self passMeCoordinates:loc.coordinate];
```

Comment: It may be quietly ignored, it may bring about the end of the Universe as we know it.  Basically, unless it's documented somehow, it's "undefined behavior".

Comment: But of course, "coordinate" is a property, so a call will occur using a null pointer, returning zero.  Likely the compiler will attempt to copy the location coordinate struct from location zero and you'll get a storage error.

Comment: @HotLicks It used to be that the results are undefined, but it seems that this changed recent. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I assume your earlier code was:

```
[self passMeCoordinates:nil];
```

The compiler complains about this because CLLocationCoordinate2D is not an object. It's a C-style struct. So, you can't pass an object/pointer (nil) where a struct is expected. (They're not the same size, etc.)

If I slightly paraphrase your code to:

```
CLLocation* loc = nil;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = loc.coordinate;
[self passMeCoordinates:coord];
```

The question comes down to "what value does `coord` have". As you may know, the rule in Objective-C is that if you send a message to nil (as we do here -- loc.coordinate is equivalent to [loc coordinate]), then you get back 0. But what if we're expecting a struct? As I just mentioned, it's not the same size as an integer. Well, it turns out that the result depends on what compiler you're using:

LLVM 3.0+ (Xcode 4.2+): returns all zeros, so it's equivalent to a coordinate of (0,0): [Can I rely on nil UIView returning CGRectZero for its frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051785/can-i-rely-on-nil-uiview-returning-cgrectzero-for-its-frame)

LLVM Earlier/GCC: a struct can be filled with garbage/undefined contents, so it could be anything.

Comment: That is interesting to know, but coord with 0,0. Well it's a valid coordinate in the sea. I would not think of it as equivalent to nil.

Comment: Yeah, agreed, but that's what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Loc.coordinate is a structure so you cannot pass nil for that.
And method that return C structure are not safe to be call on nil. 
So your warning is not about passing nil as argument.

As of your question about nil as argument. Well it depends on the method, some handle nil gracefully others don't. Refer to the documentation of those method it's usually said if you can or cannot pass nil as argument.

Comment: Just looked into this more, and updated my answer. Looks like structs are now defined to return all zeros! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051785/can-i-rely-on-nil-uiview-returning-cgrectzero-for-its-frame

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you're dealing with a `struct` property of your `location` object, and therefore `nil` will be problematic. You should only be using `nil` with objects.

But more generally, you should never assume that any method will accept `nil` as a parameter. It all varies from method to method. For the built-in classes, it will generally specify in the documentation when a `nil` parameter is acceptable. If it doesn't say that `nil` is permissible, it's wise to assume that it's not.

Whether your own code accepts a `nil` parameter is entirely dependent upon what you do with that parameter and if you're doing anything that requires it to not be `nil`, whether your code is checking for non-`nil` values and handling appropriately, etc.

As a completely random example, if you have a method that does:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:text];
```

This will generate a `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception if `text` is `nil`.

Bottom line, it all varies, method to method. Refer to the documentation for the methods in question to see if `nil` is permissible or not.

The one general exception to the "don't use `nil` unless the documentation says you can" rule is that when sending messages to a `nil` object (i.e. invoking a method on an object that is `nil`). That is permissible (but obviously does nothing). As the documentation says:

> In Objective-C, you can often send a message to `nil` with no ill effects. Return values from messages sent to nil are guaranteed to work as long as what is returned is typed as an object.

Comment: Agreed, except he's not passing nil here, since CLLocationCoordinate2D isn't an object.

Comment: @JesseRusak Absolutely. I was just trying to answer what I suspect what the more general question (others had more than adequately answered the `struct` question). I just didn't want the OP to conclude "oh, they say I can't use `nil` with a `struct`" and therefore mistakenly assume that it would be permissible when it wasn't a `struct`. I have attempted to clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime nil will get passed to your method.   The compiler does not do runtime checking , it only does compile time type checking.

Comment: Are you sure? A CLLocationCoordinate2D can't be nil; it's a struct.